# How to install Wubi without Administrator privileges in Windows

Tags: wubi, administration

Is there any way to install Wubi without Administrator privileges in Windows?

Or, if this is not possible, is there any workaround to have an Ubuntu experience while on Windows? 
Thanks.

Comment: You could run Ubuntu on an AWS account: https://aws.amazon.com/ and also [stackoverflow.com/how-do-i-setup-ubuntu-desktop-in-ec2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132575/how-do-i-setup-ubuntu-desktop-in-ec2)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not the administrator for Windows and don't have permission to install programs , no . The Ubuntu installation starts from the windows boot loader would be visible when the computer starts as a boot option . It would best to get permission to install and run Ubuntu .